# Javascript onclick not called on some computers

Tags: javascript, .net

I have an VB.NET web page that calls a javascript function when a checkbox in a datagrid view is checked or unchecked. The code works fine on my computer and for a few more people. But for most of the people the javascript function is not called at all when they check or uncheck a checkbox. All of these computers are Windows 7 and using IE 9. I also checked the IE->Internet Options->Advanced tab and the settings are the same on these machines. At this point I am out of ideas on this and google doesn't return any helpful results. I would really appreciate if someone can help me resolve this issue. Here is the code for the javascript function if that helps.

```
function SelectLineItem(pRowIndex)
{
    var vGridView=document.getElementById('dgvFSOView');
    var vLen=vGridView.rows.length;
    var i=parseInt(pRowIndex)+1;
    var intcount;
    var vtxtFcheckbox=vGridView.rows[parseInt(pRowIndex)].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
    var vFCheckbox=document.getElementById(vtxtFcheckbox); 
    var browser=navigator.appName;
    for(intcount=i;intcount<=vLen-1;intcount++)
    {
        if ((document.getElementById('hifCheck').value=="ALL") || (document.getElementById('hifCheck').value=="-1"))
        {
            var vtxtSONO=vGridView.rows[intcount].cells[3].innerText;
        }
        else if((document.getElementById('hifCheck').value!="ALL") || (document.getElementById('hifCheck').value=="-1"))
        {
            var vtxtSONO=vGridView.rows[intcount].cells[2].innerText;
        }
        if(vtxtSONO=="")
        {     
           if ((document.getElementById('hifCheck').value=="ALL") || (document.getElementById('hifCheck').value=="-1"))
           {
               var vtxttocheckbox=vGridView.rows[intcount].cells[14].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
            }
            else
            {
                var vtxttocheckbox=vGridView.rows[intcount].cells[13].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].id;
            }
            var vTCheckbox=document.getElementById(vtxttocheckbox); 

            if(vFCheckbox.checked==true)
            {
                vTCheckbox.checked=true;
            }
            else
            {
                vTCheckbox.checked=false;
            }
      }
      else
      {
       return false;
      }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This could potentially be an issues with the permissions the users have on their computers. Security settings have different levels of permissions which vary depending on how the user set up their machine.

If you are running the code locally (IE: double clicking a local .html file) you often need to enable Javascript before any javascript can run at all on the page. If it's hosted on a website (IE: www.example.com/mypage.asp) then this shouldn't be a problem.

How are you calling this function? You may also want to try using the developer tools built into IE to see if any errors are occurring, which would prevent your script from completing.

Utilizing a cross browser compatible framework like jQuery might help your checkbox change event trigger, but could be overkill depending on what how complicated your project is.

Comment: This javascript function is added to the checkbox on each row of the datagridview in RowDataBound. Here is the code snippet from RowDataBound.
    Dim vChk As CheckBox = (CType((e.Row.FindControl("chk")), CheckBox))
    vChk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelectLineItem('" & e.Row.RowIndex & "');")

Comment: What I am unable to understand here is that this same code used to work on all the machines until I made this minor change to the above mentioned javascript function.

Original Code 

    var i=parseInt(pRowIndex)+2;
    var intcount;
    var vtxtFcheckbox=vGridView.rows[parseInt(pRowIndex)+1].cells[0].getElementsByTagName

After the change

    var i=parseInt(pRowIndex)+1;
    var intcount;
    var vtxtFcheckbox=vGridView.rows[parseInt(pRowIndex)].cells[0].getElementsByTagName

Comment: I think if you used jQuery to handle these functions you're more likely to have success, as they handle any cross browser compatibility issues. www.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes do not reliably trigger the `click` event. Bind your function to the checkboxes' `change` event instead.

Comment: Thank you and I totally agree with you. But, this is an existing application and this problem has resulted from a change (mentioned in my comment to another answer on this post) I made to the javascript function. If I cannot resolve the javascript error I would switch to the Server side event.